# Deleted characters recorded in MobaXterm log

Tags: logging, mobaxterm

In MobaXterm SSH session, I type several letters randomly then delete them, but they are still recorded in log file. How can I prevent the deleted letters from being recorded in the log file?

Below is what I typed:
I typed aaa, then backspace backspace backspace, then pwd.
[what I typed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTaB5.png)

What is recorded in log file:

wlc@licheng:~$ **aaa**pwd

/home/wlc

MobaXterm personal edition v23.6